# Robocopy: How to copy assets from multiple locations to a single location and maintain a log

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface, batch, windows-command-prompt, robocopy

I have multiple folders containing assets (each folder has subfolders containing these assets .mp3, .txt, .png, etc). I want to copy all this assets along with the subfolder to a single location/folder. I was able to successfully run a robocopy command to achieve copying of assets along with subfolders from one folder to another folder:

> robocopy source target /s

I will be running a scheduler once daily to copy the assets. Also I wanted to store the name of all the copied assets in a log file. The name of the log file should be in the form of

> log_currentDate.txt

for example if the today's date is 20th Oct 2015... the name of the log file should be:

> log_20151020.txt

The next day i.e. 21st Oct 2015, it should be:

> log_20151021.txt

This log file should contain the name of all the copied assets on 20th Oct 2015, 21st Oct 2015 and so on. I created a batch command (thanks to @DavidPostill) to create a log as follows:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (
set _date=%%a%%b%%c
)
echo robocopy source target /log:D:\ABC\log%_date%.txt
```

This creates a log with the name "logTue2010.txt" (i.e. logdayddmm format). **Problem:**

1. Where does this log file gets stored? To make visible this log file, I have to write a separate command everyday as follows:

> robocopy source target /log:D:\ABC\logWed1021.txt /tee /s

2. How do I ensure that a separate copy of log is obtained each day?
3. Also with the current command, the log file contains the entire output displayed on the cmd window. I just want it to contain the name of the asset with its extension.

**EDIT:** As per @JosefZ I edited my batch file as follows:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value') do set "_date=%%G"
set "_date="%_date:~0,8%
echo robocopy source target /log:D:\ABC\log\log_%_date%.txt
robocopy source target /log:D:\ABC\log\log_%_date%.txt /S
```

I received the following output:

```
D:\ABC>D:\ABC\copy1.bat
robocopy source target /log:D:\ABC\log\log_.txt
Log File : D:\ABC\log\log_.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `YYYYMMDD`-formatted date independently of locale and regional settings using [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) against `wmic` ([Windows Management Instrumentation Command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)) and [environment variable substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value') do set "_date=%%G"
set "_date=%_date:~0,8%"
```

There are more `robocopy` [logging options](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html):

> ```
>             /L : List only - don’t copy, timestamp or delete any files.
>            /NP : No Progress - don’t display % copied.
>       /unicode : Display the status output as Unicode text.   #
>      /LOG:file : Output status to LOG file (overwrite existing log).
>   /UNILOG:file : Output status to Unicode Log file (overwrite)
>     /LOG+:file : Output status to LOG file (append to existing log).
>  /UNILOG+:file : Output status to Unicode Log file (append)
>            /TS : Include Source file Time Stamps in the output.
>            /FP : Include Full Pathname of files in the output.
>            /NS : No Size - don’t log file sizes.
>            /NC : No Class - don’t log file classes.
>           /NFL : No File List - don’t log file names.
>           /NDL : No Directory List - don’t log directory names.
>           /TEE : Output to console window, as well as the log file.
>           /NJH : No Job Header.
>           /NJS : No Job Summary.
> ```

```
robocopy B Bcopy /log:D:\ABC\log\log_%_date%.txt /S /NP /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /NC
```

Above command (note `/NP /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /NC` switches) will suppress almost all except (full-qualified) file names  in `robocopy` output. However, file names are indented with some <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> characters. Next code snippet should make output as desired:

```
>D:\ABC\log\log_%_date%.txt (
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('
    robocopy B Bcopy /S /NP /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /NC
  ') do echo(%%G
)
```

For `>` explanation, see [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). And the log file gets stored in specified folder (`D:\ABC\log\`); to ensure this, try

```
type D:\ABC\log\log_%_date%.txt
```

Comment: do I have to replace "/value" with something?

Comment: @YashSaraiya no, the `/value` is a `/FORMAT` switch moniker. `wmic OS get /VALUE` is the same as `wmic OS get  /FORMAT:"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\textvaluelist.xsl"`. Note fully qualified filename in last command; `/FORMAT:textvaluelist.xsl` should suffice

Comment: Did you see the "EDIT" in my question? Please check and give update

Comment: @YashSaraiya Sorry, adjusted wrong `set "_date="%_date:~0,8%` to right `set "_date=%_date:~0,8%"`, see position of double quotes. Accidental mistake of copy&paste

Comment: It is working fine now... But I have mentioned other issues too... like currently my log contains everything that is shown up in the cmd upon firing a command... I want only the name of the assets that are copied and not the entire summary of cmd

Comment: @YashSaraiya `/NP /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /NC` switches will suppress almost all except (full-qualified) file names.